# how to setup continuous aggregation in timescaledb for historical data

Tags: timescaledb

I'd like to have materialized data automatically calculated as new (however historical) data comes.

My data are historical time series manually added by user (application is used but data import is triggered manually). The data is stored in one table promoted to timescale. Every time user adds about 36000 rows with 100ms sampling rate (about one hour of data). The first sample is never tied to the beginning of an hour and, also, the following portion of data is not mandatory tied to the previous portion (there might be gaps).

What I want, is to have materialized data in buckets of 10 minutes, 1 hour, 1 day and the process of data materialization should run automatically.

My first confusion is should I create continuous_aggregate_policy after I created continuous aggregate. Currently I don't do that. When I inserted the first portion of data (with simple `INSERT`), I could see that the data materialized successfully (I checked this by setting `timescaledb.materialized_only = true`). Then, when I've added a lot more data, it wasn't materialized. I found the scheduler job (there is just one job) and tried to reschedule it like `SELECT alter_job(1, next_start => now());` but nothing happened, data are still not materialized (I see `last_run_status` is Success and `last_successful_finish` changed to the moment when I ran a query). However, `hypertable_schema` and `hypertable_name` fields are NULL, so I wonder if this background job is going to do anything.

Adding continuous_aggregate_policy looks not logical to me if I add historical data (like 1-hour-long data but 1 year old). As I undertand, continuous_aggregate_policy updates only recent data.

Should my option be to materialize the data manually right after I add it by calling `CALL refresh_continuous_aggregate('conditions', '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01');` ? Is data not going to materialize if I don't do this manually upon inserting the data? In the case of manual refreshing I afraid of possible data inconsistency if my application will fail for some reason between commiting the new data and calling continuous aggregate refresh query. In this case, can I just do both operations in one query? What happen if this query fails then? How do I know if the data was committed? Many uprising questions...

Next step in my project will be to automate data ingest, so the interaction with the user and supervision of that process are excluded.

So, what is the right strategy to automate creation of materialized data for manually added historical data?

P.S. re-creating materialized viewes after inserting of new data is not an option because it'll take days to complete.

Comment: Wondering if the blog posts around public datasets and open data on the Timescale blog are useful since they likely work with historic data. It's quite a big topic but if you can tie it down to specific questions after you got the outline approach it might be easier to provide good insights on this one?
Disclosure: I work for Timescale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that TimescaleDB version is 2.x. Before 2.0 creating a continuous aggregate view was always creating the corresponding policy. This change and motivation is described in [Changes in TimescaleDB 2.0](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/overview/release-notes/changes-in-timescaledb-2/#new-functions-for-size-information).

It is necessary to [create continuous aggregate policies](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/continuous-aggregates/add_continuous_aggregate_policy/) for each continuous aggregate otherwise no data will be materialized into continuous aggregates automatically. I am not sure how you were able to get data into the continuous aggregate initially.

What is the job 1 about? You can check existing jobs in [timescaledb_information.jobs](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/informational-views/jobs/). TimescaleDB usually creates a job for telemetry, so it might be it.

When you create a policy to refresh continuous aggregate, make sure to choose a refresh window, which will cover the newly inserted data at the moment the policy will run. See `start_offset` and `end_offset` parameters. Note that only fully covered buckets will be refreshed. Covering old data should not be an issue, since TimescaleDB keeps track of invalidated buckets due to newly inserted or updated data, and doesn't refresh buckets where no changes happen into.

Comment: thank you for your answer! yes, timescaleDB is 2.3.1. In v.1.x it worked without creating a policy. Now it needs policy, I've got answers also from timescale developers in slack. Now regarding initialy materialized data. So, first I've created continuous aggregates, then inserted a data into hypertable and it materialized the first time. It's strange. But maybe it has something to do with materialization threshold, see Invalidation Engine in the docs. Anyway, now I know more or less what to do to materialize my data

Comment: @Ostap What do you miss in my answer to your question? Regarding initial materialisation: can you reproduce it? It is difficult to discuss it without seeing each command and their results. To my knowledge no data will be materialised without manual refresh or policy.

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly upvoted your unswer instead of accept it. Now also accepted. By the way, in 1.6.x timescale continuous aggregates were updated without policies but just after data insert, it still runs in my first implementation, then looks like it has been changes in timescale 2.x so I was confused. Regarding initial materialization - it'll be difficult for me to build minimal example, so I'll leave it. Instead, I'll implement manual refreshing. I'm going to post my answer to the question here a bit later (with my solution to the problem). Thanks a lot for your interest!

Comment: @Ostap Thanks! I added a brief comment about before 2.0 life and reference to a document discussing changes. I guess you are aware about [user-defined actions](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/actions/), which allows to create own policies/jobs and utilising provided background job engine.

Comment: @ k-rus. No, not yet. I started with databases not so long time ago. Still a lot of to learn